# understanding external library path qmake

Tags: qt, libraries, qmake

I'm working with Qt and currently I have a problem understanding something about adding external libraries.

What I have now in my .pro file is this:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L"/home/[RIGHT PATH]" -lOMD
```

where [RIGHT PATH] is the path to where the library is

if, however I put:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L"/home/[WRONG PATH, TRASH]" -lOMD
```

it still works!

if I put:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L"/home/[RIGHT PATH]"
```

it doesn't work anymore (compiling errors because it doesn't know some functions that are in the library).

Can someone please explain to me why?

Also, I put these .so files in usr/lib so I shouldn't even have to include them here, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The statement `-L"PATH"` means **add** `PATH` the library search
  directory list.
- The statement `-lOMD` means load library `OMD` during linking.

It seems somehow your library is already in the library search path.
Which means `LIBS += -lOMD` will also work. Aside from some runtime libraries you have to specify the libraries to load.

***edit:***
`/usr/lib` is a default library search path. If you manually copy the library there, it will be found.

Comment: so even if I add the wrong path it doesn't matter because the library is in usr/lib directory as well?

Comment: I never say it was in `usr/lib`. You did something else which allow the system to retrieve `OMD`. Did you manually copied it into `usr/lib`?

Comment: yes, I did. That's why I am asking if that is the reason why, even with me giving it the wrong path, it will find it.

Comment: The "wrong path" you gave is not the only path which is searched. There are other paths which can be search by default. That's why wrote **add**  bold

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.
I thought that was what you meant by the bold, just wanted to make sure I understood correctly. Thank you.